# grunt-contrib-copy error (Error code: ENOENT)

Tags: gruntjs

I searched internet and it looks only me had this problem with grunt-contrib-copy.

```
project
  gruntfile.js
  ->app
     ->img
        ->pic1.png
        ->pic2.png
```

Result I expected:

```
project
  gruntfile.js
  ->app
     ->dist
        ->img
           ->pic1.png
           ->pic2.png
     ->img
        ->pic1.png
        ->pic2.png
```

In another word, just copy files in /project/app/img to /project/app/dist/img.

Here is my copy config, which is NOT working:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    src: ['*.*'],
    expend: true,
    cwd: 'app/img/',
    dest: 'app/dist/img/'
  }
},
```

Here is error message:
Warning: Unable to read "download.png" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

(download.png is the name of picture file)

How should I config the copy option? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo, it should be `expand` instead of `expend`. So the `cwd` property is being ignored. Try the following config instead:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    src: ['**/*'],
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'app/img/',
    dest: 'app/dist/img/'
  }
},
```

The glob pattern `*.*` is probably not necessary as `*` will already match all files (unless you're specifically trying to match *only files with a `.` in them.*) Try using `src: '*'` to match all files within the single folder or `src: '**/*'` to match all files and folders within the `cwd`.

Comment: It solved my problem perfectly! Thank you! But isn't 'e' and 'a' are the same letter on keyboard? No, they are not. Just kidding.